# Does Intel provide its own C library on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, fortran, intel-fortran, icc

Compiling the following code on Linux

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  return;
}
```

using `icc` version 15.0.0

```
icc -no-cxxlib -no-gcc-include-dir test.c
```

produces a dynamic executable that is linked against glibc:

```
ldd ./a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffc601b6000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000038f0c00000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000038efc00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000038f0400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000038ef800000)
```

---

The same is true for Fortran using `ifort` version 15.0.0 and the corresponding code

```
program test
  print *,'Hello world'
end program
```

compiled with

```
ifort -no-cxxlib -no-gcc-include-dir test.F90
```

Again, the resulting library is linked against glibc:

```
ldd ./a.out 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff483da000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00000038f0c00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00000038f0000000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00000038efc00000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00000038f2c00000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00000038f0400000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00000038ef800000)
```

---

**tl;dr;** Do the Intel compilers provide their own C library on Linux? If yes, how can I link against it?

I know that for the Windows version, there is (was?) an alternative C library shipped with the compiler/runtime libraries. However, I couldn't find any library of that kind shipped by Intel on Linux.

Comment: [Linking against glibc doesn't make the entire executable subject to the GPL.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPL_linking_exception) Note: I am not a lawyer in any country in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: @R_Kapp The linking exception applies to libraries shipped with GCC (libm, libstdc++, etc) but unfortunately not to glibc itself.

Comment: There's a separate [runtime library exception](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gcc-exception.html) as well that covers glibc.

Comment: But this is actually not the point. The question is whether Intel does ship its own library and how I could use it.

Comment: AFAIK they do not. They also use the GNU STL for the C++ compiler.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question initially. At any rate, my understanding of the law here is that unless you actually ship glibc with the product, instead of letting your customers use whatever version of glibc they have locally on their flavor of Linux, you should be good to go. This is how I've seen it done everywhere I've worked. To answer the question, though, no there is no library shipped with Intel.

Comment: @R_Kapp: There is no problem dynamically linking against the glibc (or any other LGPL lirary). AFAIK the problem arises if you statically link, i.e. include into your code. How else would one be able to write proprietary code for Linux which itself is under GPL? (Disclaimer: IANAL. The FSF has some articles about this subject).

Comment: Please, I don't want this (L)GPL debate. I am personally fine with  dynamic linking against glibc (I don't have any code that I distribute/contribute to that isn't open source). I was just curious whether Intel does ship a standard C library or not. If the answer is no I can live with that! Also, this is not asking for a replacement or another off-site resource (don't know where that idea comes from, I have everything I need), I'm just curious.

Comment: On Windows, the situation is different. The operating system doesn't have a C library; that comes with toolchains, such as Microsoft's Visual Studio, and has to be distributed with applications. (Otherwise your program depends on some random version of the run time that was installed by another application, which rudely stuck it into the system folder.)  The MS C library has a history of seriously lagging behind ISO C, which is a one excellent reason to provide something else if you provide a C compiler. Look how MinGW is crippled compared to Cygwin.

Comment: Also, on Windows, the job of providing just a C library is smaller than on Linux. The reason is that even if you provide a C library with your compiler on Windows, you don't provide the Windows interface: that's still encapsulated in the system DLL's.  The C library really is just C stuff. (Mostly: there are pseudo-POSIX things in Microsoft's C library, and conio.h and such.)  On Linux, though, if you don't link glibc, you have nothing. Not even wrappers for dispatching the bare system calls.  Reproducing everything which is in glibc is a big job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intel doesn't provide any glibc or libstdc++ .  In the beginning of itanium years ago there was dinkumware , and intel supplies libraries for MIC with MPSS.  For Windows the Microsoft SDK is required.
IIRC Icc 15.0 would normally be run with g++ 4.7 or 4.9 on path.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/328248/intel-linux-compiler-13-0-gnu-compatibility-rev6.pdf

Comment: Could you edit the reference and a suitable citation into your answer? Links and documents on the internet have a tendency to vanish ;) Thanks a lot!